# Pyperclip copy causing an OSerror

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyperclip

I am trying to learn python using https://automatetheboringstuff.com.

While on IDLE (Python 3.5 - 64 Bits), windows 8.1), pyperclip.copy('test') gives the following error message

> > > pyperclip.copy('test')
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >           pyperclip.copy('test')
> > >         File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pyperclip__init__.py", line 53, in _copyWindows
> > >           ctypes.cdll.msvcrt.wcscpy(ctypes.c_wchar_p(pchData), text)
> > >       OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000000

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be the 64-bit version of Python on some windows PCs.

I had this problem when using the same version of Python 3.5 as you (64-bit - Windows x86-64 executable installer). I didn't have this problem in Python 3.4, but I am using the 32-bit version of that release. I just downloaded and installed the 32-bit version of Python 3.5 (Windows x86 executable installer) and it doesn't give me the issue when using pyperclip.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't have a Win8 or Win10 box handy for testing, but this info really helps. I'm marking the source code of Pyperclip with this answer so we can fix it in a near version.