# pandasDataFrame.to_clipboard() error

Tags: python, python-3.5, access-violation, liclipse, eoserror

I have this code to enable CTRL+C copy on the selected contents of a tkinter.ttk treeview:

```
def Copy(event):
    '''
    Copies the selected treeview items to the
    clipboard. Includes Column numbers.
    '''
    selectedRows = []
    selectedRows.append(self.maindata.columns)

    for i in self.tree.selection():
        selectedRows.append(self.tree.item(i)['values'])

    d = pd.DataFrame(selectedRows)

    d.to_clipboard(index=False)

self.tree.bind("<Control-Key-c>", Copy)
```

This was working fine in plan text.py files executed in IDLE but I'm using the Liclipse IDE for a more confortable debugging experience now and I get the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programming\Anaconda3_4.2.0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:\Programming\EclipseWorkspace\AssetManager\workingTreeview.py", line 90, in Copy
    d.to_clipboard(index=False)
  File "E:\Programming\Anaconda3_4.2.0\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1202, in to_clipboard
    clipboard.to_clipboard(self, excel=excel, sep=sep, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Programming\Anaconda3_4.2.0\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\clipboard.py", line 98, in to_clipboard
    clipboard_set(objstr)
  File "E:\Programming\Anaconda3_4.2.0\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\clipboard.py", line 85, in _copyWindows
    ctypes.cdll.msvcrt.wcscpy(ctypes.c_wchar_p(pchData), text)
OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000000
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening and what I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32676543/pyperclip-copy-causing-an-oserror

Comment: I didn't see it - im not using paperclip though so I'm not sure installing a different version of python is the first step is take.  Maybe there are some other ideas out there?

Comment: Yeah I know. But pyperclip and `df.to_clipboard()` are doing similar things, Hence I pointed.

Comment: Seems like a a bug in pandas (running on LiClipse is just making it visible to you).